# I get an Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException trying to start the App

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-4.4-kitkat

when I try to start my App on Android 4.4 it cirashes in line

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

in the MainActivity.cs

with Error "Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08005a'"

on newer Android versions it's working.

Comment: Did you try deleting bin/obj and clean buiding?

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: you are using something not supported by Android 4.4 is what I feel

Comment: Check your project, see if you have two `abc_vector_test.xml` , one in `res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml` and one in `res/drawable-v21/abc_vector_test.xml` . That would mean your APK was not built with --no-version-vectors AAPT option, as Android Developers documentation hints to:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution

Comment: there is only one abc_vector_text.xml and it's in res/drawable

Comment: I don't suggest you to test you app on such an old version.